# Building libwebsockets library with MinGW

Tags: c, libwebsockets

I'm trying to build libwebsockets library using minGW by following the steps available at https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets/blob/master/READMEs/README.build.md
under the section 
@section cmwmgw Building on Windows (MinGW)

I'm doing

```
cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\Users\pro12\Desktop\lib\libwebsockets
```

the directory "C:\Users\pro12\Desktop\lib\libwebsockets" contains the source files for the libwebsockets library and I'm runnning this command from

```
C:\Users\pro12\Desktop\libwebsockets\build
```

but it giving me error

```
CMake Error: The source directory "C:/Users/pro12/Desktop/libwebsockets/build" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
```

Can anyone tell what i'm doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: You should run `make` from the project's root folder (where the `CMakeLists.txt ` file is placed). Also, try to install the library to a different folder (not the source code folder)... perhaps a sub-folder. The installation process might be conflicting with the build process.

Comment: When i'm running cmake from root directory and installing it to a subfolder i'm gettng this   `CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (message):`
  The C compiler

    `"C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe"`
  is not able to compile a simple test program.
  It fails with the following output:
   `Change Dir: C:/Users/pro12/Desktop/lib/libwebsockets/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp`

Comment: I'm not sure what the second error is about just yet, but it certainly sounds like an improvement over the first error (seems you're failing at a more advanced stage, where the compiler is engaged).... What error do you get if you try to install to an unrelated folder (somewhere not in the `libwebsockets` tree)?

Comment: Getting the same error as above when trying to install at `C:/Users/pro12/Desktop/somefolder/`

Comment: Could be a permission related error. Make sure you have permission to write/execute for all the folders and files in the project's folder (CMake and the compiler will write stuff in `CMakeTmp`)  or maybe run CMake as admin (which might not work). Also, consider running the command with `--debug-trycompile` as suggested [here](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=9286), this will give you more information.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are building it in `C:\Users\pro12\Desktop\libwebsockets\build`, but your source code is in `C:\Users\pro12\Desktop\libwebsockets`, obviously cmake could not find the  CMakeLists.txt, try

> cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles"
>   -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\Users\pro12\Desktop\lib\libwebsockets **..**

Do **not** omit the `..` two tailing dots: these indicate the parent directory!

Answer (score -1):

Your libwebsockets "CMakeLists.txt" file is exist in

> "C:/Users/pro12/Desktop/libwebsockets"

but your "cmake" CMD is running in

> "C:/Users/pro12/Desktop/libwebsockets/build"

so , you should:

> cmake .. -G "MSYS Makefiles"
> -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\Users\pro12\Desktop\lib\libwebsockets

it can specify "CMakeList.txt" file's directory